# Get image data for Direct3d rendering stream

Tags: c++, directshow, direct3d

I would like to get at the raw image data, as in a pointed to a byte array or something like that, of the image output from a direct3d app without actually rendering it to the monitor.

I need to do this so that I can render direct3d as a directshow source filter

Visual studio 2008 c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a surface to which you're going to render as an instance of [`IDirect3DSurface9`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205892%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Set it as the target for your rendering with [`IDirect3DDevice9::SetRenderTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174455%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So in a nutshell, I would call the setrendertarget in the initialization, and then after each frame is rendered. LockRect to get a D3DLOCKED_RECT which would provide me a pointer to the image bytes?  Is that it in a nutshell?

Comment: Oh and calling setrendertarget will prevent it from being rendered to the screen, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You can also lock the back buffer.

Comment: I am not very familiar with d3d.  How would I lock the back buffer to get at the pixel data?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174379(v=VS.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205896(v=VS.85).aspx